# How to allow connect to CF app through some TCP ports?

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I have a Web App deployed to CF which I can reach through 80 port. And also I want to connect to this app through some TCP ports. 
Is it possible with Cloud Foundry? What do I need to configure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use "tcp routing", start reading here -> https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/adminguide/enabling-tcp-routing.html